# Trying to limit the use of a form x times using localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to limit the use of a form only for example three times and save the values. To then display, all with localStorage. How can get this? Help please.

HTML

```
<form name=colors>
  <input type="Radio" name="colorin" value="white" checked> White
  <br>
  <input type="Radio" name="colorin" value="red"> Red
  <br>
  <input type="Radio" name="colorin" value="green"> Green
  <br>
  <input type="Button" name="" value="Click" onclick="color()">
  <div id='output'></div>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function color(){
  if (localStorage.getItem('thing') === null) {
    var i
    var colors = document.getElementsByName('colorin')
    for (i=0;i<colors.length;i++){
       if (colors[i].checked)
          var answer = colors[i].value;   
    }
    localStorage.setItem('thing', answer);
    var fillin = document.getElementById('output');
    fillin.innerHTML=localStorage.getItem('thing');
  }
  else{
     alert('Exists!!!');
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting stuck? Edit more details and explanations

Comment: For example, you only can press click 3 times, no more. How can I solve this? Do I need more than one localStorage? Sorry for my explanation before

Comment: I edited my answer. This edit will enable you to store all your selected elements in `localStorage`. as a result `localStorage` will retain in its memory a history of your selected elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is another key value pair in your Localstorage. something like Count.

here is a sample code i tweaked your code to add a condition to limit click for 3 times.

```
function color(){
  if (localStorage.getItem('count') === null) {
  localStorage.setItem('count', 0);
     saveColor();
  } else if(localStorage.getItem('count') < 3) {
  var count = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('count'), 10);
   count = count+1;
    localStorage.setItem('count', count);
     saveColor();
  } else {
     alert('3 times limit reached');
  }
}
  function saveColor() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('thing') === null) {
    var i;
    var answer;
    var colors = document.getElementsByName('colorin');
    for (i=0;i<colors.length;i++){
       if (colors[i].checked)
          answer = colors[i].value;   
    }
    localStorage.setItem('thing', answer);
    var fillin = document.getElementById('output');
    fillin.innerHTML=localStorage.getItem('thing');
  }
  else{
     alert('Exists!!!');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I save in the 'thing' localStorage the 3 values? or do I need use 3 localStorages? Thanks

Comment: what do u mean by 3 values?

Comment: btw localstorage is always 1 and you can have as many key value pairs as you want

Comment: for example, the first click white, the second click white again and third click red without delete the previous values. (one key, three values)

Comment: Yes you can store multiple values just make your answers as an array

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working fiddle to save you from the trouble : http://jsbin.com/ojejaz/2/edit

**EDIT**

This edit will enable you to store all your selected elements in `localStorage` in the form of an `[]`

Its always good practice to take objects from `localStorage` and keep it on DOM `ready`, and reuse the object:

```
  //get required items from localStorage
 var choices = localStorage.getItem('colors');
 var noOfTimes = Number(localStorage.getItem("no"));
```

Here `no` is the number of times user has entered your page. 
Functions used :
`color` - your original function
`disableButton` - code to disable the HTML button

Here's the updated `color` function

```
  //get required items from localStorage
 var choices = localStorage.getItem('colors');
 var noOfTimes = Number(localStorage.getItem("no"));

  // convert answers into an empty array if choices is null, or use choices
 var answers = (choices === null) ? [] : choices;

 //check if clicked number is more than 3 on page refresh
 if(noOfTimes >= 3)
 {
   disableButton();
 } 

 //your original function
 function color() { 
     // to disable button, rechecking
     noOfTimes = Number(localStorage.getItem("no"));

     //disable click if the number visited is greater than 3
     if (noOfTimes >= 3) {
        disableButton();
     } 
     // else increase visited count and search for the selected option, and push into array 
     else {
        localStorage.setItem('no', noOfTimes+ 1);
        var i, colors = document.getElementsByName('colorin');
        for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            if (colors[i].checked)
            {
              answers.push(colors[i].value);
            }
        }
        // re-store the updated array in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('colors', answers);
        // print out the elements in the array
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = answers;
     }
  }

  // to disable button after 3 times clicked
  function disableButton()
  {
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[3].disabled = true;
  }
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to keep previous values, this code re-write the value of the localStorage, no?

Comment: no it wont..it'll keep the old values and add the new ones with the old ones..look at the output : http://jsbin.com/ojejaz/2